# Reporting on customers with counts of child records

Tags: netsuite

We have a record type called Asset. Each Asset has a Customer as its parent. (It's a one to many relationship - Customer to Assets.)

Each Asset has a field called Colour, with possible values Red, Green and Blue.

I want to make a saved search or report to show me a list of all the Customers, and for each Customer the number of Red Assets, Green Assets and Blue Assets.

I can't see how to do this without adding three custom fields to Customer, to store the number of Red Assets, Green Assets and Blue assets respectively, and then adding these fields to the results of a Customer saved search.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add 3 result columns Formula (Numeric) Summary Type (Sum)
`type(SUM) DECODE({Colour}, 'Red', 1)`
`type(SUM) DECODE({Colour}, 'Green', 1)`
`type(SUM) DECODE({Colour}, 'Blue', 1)`

You would also still need the result Customer Grouped

Answer (score 1):

Start a new saved search against the Asset Record.

On the Results tab, click Remove All and add the following new lines to your search.

Field: Customer, Summary: Group

Field: Colour, Summary: Group

Field: Internal ID, Summary: Count

When you run this search, it will return results with one row per customer per colour and display the count of assets for each colour and each customer.

Comment: Is there any way to get all three totals on one line?

Comment: Yes.  Create three new columns in your Results that are all type Formula (Numeric).  The formula would be something like:  `case when {custrecord_colour} = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end`.  Set the Summary column to Sum.  Remove the previous Colour field from the result list.

Comment: 'Set the Summary column to Sum' - which Summary column?

Comment: On the Results tab of a saved search, there's a column labeled Summary that contains the values 'Group', 'Minimum', 'Maximum', 'Average', and 'Sum'.